# SSRS 2012 .rdl exposed in aspx page hosted as a web part in SharePoint Online 2013

Tags: web-part, sharepoint-online, reporting-services, aspx

From what I've read, there's no standard option for adding SSRS 2012 reports to SharePoint Online 2013. Instead, would it be possible to expose a report rdl in an aspx page hosted in SharePoint Online 2013? I need to make use of the existing authentication structure we have in SharePoint which is why I need to host it on a SharePoint site. Any insight is much appreciated. Thanks!